# How would I kill every one on earth with only $1000

Tags: humans, death, crime, simulated-worlds

Well, this is a wacky one. I only have $1000 dollars how would I get rid of everyone on the planet.
(this is all hypothetical)

Comment: We don't write your story for you.

Comment: Its not a story, just a mind game. I'll make a story later.

Comment: Do you need to get rid of everyone or just your perception of everyone?

Comment: You can't. We don't currently have the technological ability to get rid of everyone on the planet. Even nuclear war would leave *some* survivors.

Comment: Both. How would you do it and why? @Trevor

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Worldbuilding.SE. As a rule, please don't accept an answer until 24 hours have passed since asking your question. This allows users in all timezones the chance to give you an answer. If an answer has already been accepted, many users will not bother to expend the effort answering your question, and you may miss out on better responses.

Comment: This kind of question has been asked many times...and closed each time. Random "hypothetical" may be fun, but do not seem related to the purpose of this site.

Comment: One would think that if it was *possible* it would have been attempted. One grand is not that much money. I guess the closest you can get is @Trevor's hint of "get rid of the perception of everyone" - you can buy good glasses that block sight and good noise cancelling headphones. And you're set. You may even get away with a decent VR headset, so you never need to see anybody else for the rest of your life (although, that might end shortly from lack of food and water).

Comment: @VLAZ : I could achieve all that for free with a sharp stick, poke out theyes & puncture the ear drums :) a VR headset with selective active noise cancelling to filter out voices could work for the sound & I can imagine VR goggles that do the same for anything human shaped to take care of the vision, you shouldn't starve then because you still see everything else : Or we could go straight to the brain & some sort of hypnosis so you can't see or hear anyone else.

Comment: @Pelinore when I said "VR" I meant like "being at home hooked to the PC". So, like the current level tech of VR headsets. So, basically, lock yourself at home in a virtual world and never go out. You seem to have something more advanced in mind that is probably bleeding into AR. At any rate, the reason I suggested starvation is that without going out or interacting with others, it's hard to get food. Even with a mobile AR tech that blocks people from your vision, you would still have a hard time getting food, unless you scavenge or farm. Not sustainable for the general case but maybe for some.

Comment: @VLAZ : No not AR (that adds stuff, this removes stuff) : so, ER then? : 'Edited Reality' : hmm, wonder if that's been copyrighted yet :)

Comment: @Pelinore might make a good basis for a question. Something like "how do I make people see a *different* world with tech glasses but not by adding stuff".

Comment: @VLAZ : I've already the answer for that, AI with object recognition & photo editing software, the camera records the image the AI picks out any human shapes & faces then edits the image which is then passed on to what's essentially standard VR Goggles, done in real time we're going to need some serious processing power to avoid any significant enough delay to make the individual overly clumsy.

Comment: @VLAZ : Actually I can see a market for that, you've fallen out with cousin Edith & she's going to be at great aunt Wendy's (14th) wedding, you want to go but you don't want to spoil the event (for yourself) by having to see cousin Edith there .. ERHire is the answer! if you can provide us with enough photos & sound recordings of cousin Edith we can pre-tune one of our headsets so you can attend & never see or hear her while you're there! while at the same time being able to see & hear everyone else perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bribe a Ph.D. student for his access to a genetic-engineering lab, design a deadly virus with long incubation period, release in the nearest international airport.

You will need to know how to design such viruses. If you do not know that, use $1000 to apply to a bunch of Ph.D. programs in bioengineering.

Finally, $1000 is a enough money to get a place to stay for a few weeks, which is enough to find a job, which will earn you more money, which you can use to advance your agenda.

Comment: If you're willing to wait a few years, maybe you could even buy a do-it-yourself CRISPR gene sequencing kit. (But I hope not, for this exact reason.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried Kickstarter? With a good enough pitch you might be able to raise funds for a lethal zombie-creating bioweapon or a black hole generator or a beacon to signal hostile aliens.

Comment: Funny but would people actually fund it?

Comment: If there's something in it for them -- if they think you're only going to kill other people (eg some minority or other group  they hate)  you might get some support. Or maybe you say "I'm going to kill 50% of thje population, fund me and you can be in the 50% that survives and gets their stuff."

Answer (score -2):

Buy a heat coil of reasonable size, then contain some anthrax from Siberian permafrost inside a metal container. Put it in the CRISPR and make it much, much more contagious. Go to JFK Airport, and go nuts. You may have to repeat several times.

Comment: Anthrax isn't usefully contagious, so this doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @jdunlop I edited to explain this.

Comment: Getting from Siberia to JFK just once is going to blow most, if not all, of your budget.

Comment: @NuclearWang I never said you had to do it in a timely manner.